# Compare time in different dates in Android

Tags: android, date, time, calendar, sms

I want to send an alert sms, if the current time is in between 9pm today and 9am tomorrow. That is, dates are different. How can I implement this? Anybody please help me.I don't know how to compare time in different dates.I'm attaching my code(output obtained) with two time intervals. 
`
    package com.example.alert;

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlertActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText Phnumber,Alert;
Button Send;

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String CurrentTime=hours + ":" + minutes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert);

Phnumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
Alert=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.smsBody);
Send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);

Send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), CurrentTime,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(hours>=10&& hours<=20){
              String phoneNo = Phnumber.getText().toString();
                 String msg = Alert.getText().toString(); 
             SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);    
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message was not Sent",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
});

    }






}
```

`

Comment: if the current time is in between 9pm today and 9am tomorrow?? what this mean ??

Comment: Which is your input date format ?Example 9:00AM 15-01-2014

Comment: You have to add the date along with the time  to get the exact difference. otherwise u can't get the difference between to time in difference days

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
                Date date =dateFormat.parse(result_string);
                Date currentDate=dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date()));

                if(date.compareTo(currentDate)>0){
                ////Do your thing
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want time between after 9PM to before 9Am you can use following condition..

```
if(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)> 20 || cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)< 9)
{
    // do your stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create two calendar dates.

```
 Calendar calendar_before = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar_before .set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, yourday);
 calendar_before .set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, yourhour);
 calendar_before .set(Calendar.MINUTES, yourminutes);
 calendar_before .set(Calendar.SECONDS, yourseconds);

 Calendar calendar_after = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar_after .set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, yourday);
 calendar_after .set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, yourhour);
 calendar_after .set(Calendar.MINUTES, yourminutes);
 calendar_after  .set(Calendar.SECONDS, yourseconds);

 Calendar cNow = Calendar.getInstance();

 [...]

 // check if your systime is between...
 if(cNow.getTimeInMillis() > calendar_before.getTimeInMillis() && cNow.getTimeInMillis() < calendar_after.getTimeInMillis())
 {
  // do something...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeUtils obj = new DateTimeUtils();
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, hh:mm a");

try {

Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("Thu Jan 15 09:56:00 GMT+05:30 2015");
Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("Thu Jan 16 09:56:00 GMT+05:30 2015");

obj.printDifference(date1, date2);

} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
 //1 minute = 60 seconds
 //1 hour = 60 x 60 = 3600
 //1 day = 3600 x 24 = 86400
public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

//milliseconds
long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
System.out.println("different : " + different);

long secondsInMilli = 1000;
long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
different = different % daysInMilli;

long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
different = different % hoursInMilli;

long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
different = different % minutesInMilli;

long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

System.out.printf(
    "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
    elapsedDays,
    elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);

}
```

Change your date input format according to your input

Answer (score 0):

How to display `System.out.printf` into Toast

```
System.out.printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", elapsedDays, elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);
```